# Is this a scuff on my hardwood floor? How can I fix it?

Tags: flooring

We've tried using a whole bunch of wood cleaning products for this and similar marks on our floor, but nothing seems to work. What exactly am I dealing with here and how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: can you feel it on the surface?

Comment: I cannot feel it. I can't even see it if I don't look at it from a certain angle.